# How do I resend a message in Minecraft, on mobile?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios, android, version-differences

In the console and desktop versions of Minecraft (to include [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)), you can resend a chat message by opening the chat window, and pressing the appropriate up key or button and sending the message.

This also allows you to go back through your previously sent messages for the session.

How do I accomplish this on mobile versions?

Comment: I used to use Gboard, which I believe gave me access to a tab with arrow keys. Maybe something like exists on yours.

Answer (score 1):

Custom keyboards (such as Gboard, thank you [@c1uq92](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/274566/c1uq92)) often have the ability to use arrow keys which the game will interpret and allow you to cycle back through previous commands or messages you have sent.